# Controller is not active in watchOS 3

Tags: ios, beta, watchos-3

I have a WKInterfaceController that has a group with a label and a WKInterfaceTable, each time `-(void)willActivate` is called I decide if to show the label or the table, sometimes (30%) I get a warningMessage saying: 
*WatchKit: Controller is not active. Discarding call for InterfaceController key=1 property=ht value=175 value class="__NSCFNumber"* even though I check each time that `[[WKExtension sharedExtension] applicationState] == WKApplicationStateActive`
when this happens the UI does not show/ gets stuck until I lower my wrist and raise it back again so `-(void)willActivate` will be called.

any ideas?